# CiviCRM access for Wordpress custom group users

Tags: wordpress, groups, permissions, acl

I am using CiviCRM 5.8.1 (update to 5.8.2 will be done shortly) on Wordpress 5.0.1 with German localization. For extended permission management on WP, I use Advanced Access Manager.

I created a group for the office users and granted them access in CiviCRM - Administration - User and Roles - Access control and granted them all necessary permissions including CiviCRM access.

Wordpress and CiviCRM user are properly matching (the WP user ID is listed the respective contact of the CiviCRM user).

Nevertheless, except for users with the WP Administrator role, all menu items of the CiviCRM backend except for search, contacts and CiviSEPA Dashboard keep invisible.

I tried it with different groups and also ensured that on the WP side, all capabilities in AAA with relation to CiviCRM are enabled.

To exclude side effects I removed all previously existing CiviCRM specific permission configurations (except for the administrator), including CiviCRM groups, allocations between WP and CiviCRM groups and ACL.

Anybody an idea where else to look? I tried to find hints by searching but presently I am stuck. Thanks!

Comment: After some further tries, I disabled the CiviSEPA permissions for these WP roles and the other menu entries appeared.

Comment: Hi Andreas - it sounds like this is an 'answer'. perhaps you don't have enough reputation yet, but when you do, pls add it as an Answer and 'accept' it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the CiviSEPA extension messes with the menu for users without administrative permissions. Disabling this extension in the ACL for the non-admin groups solves the problem